# how to add signature to protobuf messges?

Tags: protocol-buffers, signature

Is there a common way to sign protobuf messages? what I can imagine is to Add a data field and a signature field in a message, and use SerializeToArray(in cpp) or ToByteArray(in c#) to get raw bytes, and then use md5 or sha256 .. etc to calculate the hash value, then assign the hash value to the field 'sign'. Bue I don't know if there is any different with the raw bytes between different languages, or in proto2 and proto3?

Answer (score 2):

The approach you discuss for signing is fine for integrity validation purposes, as long as your hashing algorithm is strong enough. If it is for anything stronger than an integrity checksum, you should probably use a true cryptographic hash (with public+private keys), as anyone can otherwise sign their own arbitrary payload, defeating the point.

You also seen to discuss determinism. The raw bytes in protobuf are not entirely deterministic. There are multiple valid ways of representing the same payload in protobuf, including:

- reordering fields (numerical order is a "should", not a "must")
- including or omitting zeros (different between proto2 and proto3)
- packed vs sequential "repeated" encoding
- the reality that "map" is usually backed by some platform-specific inbuilt map/dictionary type, which commonly **do not define order**, so in theory it can vary every time
- not really an issue in reality, but in theory you can encode a varint with an arbitrary length (up to 10 bytes) simply by including unnecessary groups of zero bytes; similar to in text (JSON, etc) saying that 42, 042, 0042 and 0000000042 all represent the same integer; nobody *does that*, but: it would be valid